# Assembly Language - print devices

Tags: usb, device, interrupt, bios, tty

How can I get numbers of all devices for 13h interruption and print it? For example my BIOS support USB booting, but dl=81h-90h not working. Therefore I need to see numbers of all devices...
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

BIOS may report failure on those devices if they're not plugged in. AFAIK there's not a way to iterate the devices directly, so you might be able to just write a little loop that tests each device number (you could use `INT 13h AH=08h` to test drive parameters).

Comment: Any particular reason for downvoting a year-old post?